# In java, how to initialize final parameters after a loop which may or not initialize them

Tags: java

I'm using java
I have two final parameters.

```
final String para1;
final String para2;
```

I have a loop to initialize them,like:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.size(); i++){
 if(i==array.get(i)){
  para1 = something;
  para2 = something;
 }
}
```

but intellij will say that:para1 and para2 may not have been initialized.
How to change my code?
I have to keep para1 and para2 final, and I want to assign them to be null if they are not initialized

Comment: Add a boolean which tells you if para1 is initialized. If not set para1 to null. This wont work for primitive types as stated by @rgettman

Comment: You can't assign `null` to a primitive type such as `int`.

Comment: Sorry, they are strings not int...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use two other temporary variables:

```
int t1 = 0;
int t2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    if (i == array.get(i)) {
        t1 = something;
        t2 = something;
    }
}
para1 = t1;
para2 = t2;
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter but I think may due to t1,t2 are ints and something is string

Comment: @SpringLearner As I wrote the answer, all variables were int! Note that OP edited the question afterwards.